# SQL Server check if value is substring inside isnull

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, isnull

I have a field in UI interface that passes to a stored procedure a null value (when field is unfilled) or a contract number when it is filled. Substrings of the contract number are accepted as input.
Inside the procedure, I need to filter the results by this parameter.
I need something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName tn
WHERE
tn.ContractNumber LIKE ISNULL('%' + @contractNumber + '%', tn.ContractNumber)
```

What do you think it is the best approach? Problem is that using a condition like this does not return values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tableName tn
WHERE  tn.ContractNumber LIKE '%' + @contractNumber + '%'
    OR @contractNumber IS NULL
```

You are really checking multiple condition, so having them separated reads more intuitive (for most people, anyway).

I assume this is just a sample query, and you are not selecting `*` in reality...

Comment: Thank you! I think that worked. I have several checks in the where clause that need verifying according to this condition but it looks ok at first glance.

Comment: If you have many conditions with `AND` as well as `OR`, don't forget to use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tableName tn
WHERE  tn.ContractNumber LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@contractNumber, '%') + '%'
```